# Why might I not be getting any results from MiniProfiler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I can't seem to get any results from [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/).

I can see the XHR POST to `/mini-profiler-resources/results` returning a 404. The chrome request inspector gives me a standard server 404 page.

[image]

A GET on the same URL also returns a 404, but there is a message saying that "no results were found for the specified id" (I did add the id in the querystring).

When I look at `/mini-profiler-resources/results-index` it just gives me an empty table with the field headings in - name, started, sql, duration, etc.

I've tried a few things - details below - at this stage I am at a loss as to what I can try next. Any pointers or suggestions for debugging this problem would be much appreciated.

---

### Installed Packages:

- MiniProfiler (v3.2.0.157)
- MiniProfiler.EF6 (v3.0.11)
- MiniProfiler.MVC4 (v3.0.11)

Where MVC4 also caters for MVC5. Which this project is.

---

### Relevant Code:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize();
        MiniProfiler.Settings.Results_List_Authorize = IsUserAllowedToSeeMiniProfilerUI;
        MiniProfiler.Settings.MaxJsonResponseSize = int.MaxValue;
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ProfilingActionFilter());
        var copy = ViewEngines.Engines.ToList();
        ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
        foreach (var item in copy)
        {
            ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new ProfilingViewEngine(item));
        }
    }


    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsLocal)
        {
            // this IS being hit
            MiniProfiler.Start();
        }
    }


    protected void Applicaton_EndRequest()
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop(discardResults: false);
    }


    private bool IsUserAllowedToSeeMiniProfilerUI(HttpRequest httpRequest)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

In HomeController.cs:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var profiler = MiniProfiler.Current;
    using (profiler.Step("Doing complex stuff"))
    {
        using (profiler.Step("Step A"))
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
        }
        using (profiler.Step("Step B"))
        { 
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

And in MasterLayout.cshtml:

```
@using StackExchange.Profiling; 

... 

@MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
```

---

### I've Tried:

I  have set `discardResults` to `false`, like this:

```
    protected void Applicaton_EndRequest()
    {
        MiniProfiler.Stop(discardResults: false);
    }
```

---

I can confirm that `MiniProfiler.Start()` IS getting hit when the page loads.

---

I can also confirm that the `mini-profiler-resources/` route IS being found (using [Haack's Route Debugger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger/))

---

I have the following item in the `<handlers>` section of `web.config`, and it is in the correct section (e.g. [this guy](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/issues/32) mistakenly put it in the ELMAH config ).

```
  <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

---

I have set all my output caching to `1` second.

---

I was using a custom `applicationhost.config` file to test on a custom url.

I tried removing the custom url bindings and just using the standard localhost:51347.

I also tried putting the snippet below into `applicationhost.config` instead of the standard web.config.

```
<add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

---

In `applicationhost.config` I tried changing

`<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />`

to

`<section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />`

---

I've added the following into application_start:

`MiniProfiler.Settings.MaxJsonResponseSize = int.MaxValue;`

---

As recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027301/1778169), I have tried uninstalling all related packages and reinstalling them in this order:

- MiniProfiler
- MiniProfiler.MVC4
- MiniProfiler.EF6

---

### Update

9 days on, the bounty expired and still no joy :(

If anybody reading this in the future has ideas / suggestions, I'd really like to hear them. MiniProfiler is such a great tool and I'm disappointed that I haven't been able to get it working on this occasion.

If I do find the answer myself, I'll post it.

Comment: What querying technology are you using? EF? Dapper? Raw ASP.Net? Something else?

Comment: I'm using EF6.0

Comment: Have you installed the MiniProfiler.EF6 Nuget package?

Comment: Yeah I've installed MiniProfiler (v3.2.0.157), MiniProfiler.EF6 (v3.0.11) and MiniProfiler.MVC4 (v3.0.11).  Where MVC4 also caters for MVC5. Which this project is.

Comment: And you've run `MiniProfilerEF6.Initialize()` in `Application_Start` I presume?

Comment: Yeah I have. Sorry ErikE, I should have put all this in the question. Doing this now.

Comment: What is `ProfilingActionFilter` and `ProfilingViewEngine` doing?

Comment: They're part of the `MiniProfiler.MVC4` package - they automatically profile controllers / views, without needing to wrap them in profiling "step" syntax.  Seen in action here: https://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/07/25/Automatically+instrumenting+an+MVC3+app

Comment: Check your `web.config` for a duff runtime > assemblyBinding > dependentAssembly entry for MiniProfiler, specifically one where the redirect is pointing at the *wrong* version, i.e. not the version that you've got installed. I've seen this cause oddities for MVC before but can't remember exactly what - I *think* it was having a redirect pointing to an *older* version than was present

Answer (score 1):

After running into the same issue I found the answer here which worked fine.
http://www.mukeshkumar.net/articles/mvc/performance-test-with-miniprofiler-in-asp-net-mvc

If you get an error after running application with MiniProfiler.Mvc4 or MiniProfiler.Mvc3 which state “/mini-profiler-resources/includes.js 404 not found” then simply add the following line of code in Web.Config inside web server section.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*"
               verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule"
               resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>   
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is one of the things I tried, but it didn't help my situation.